# Write factorial with while loop python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, factorial

I am new and do not know a lot about Python. Does anybody know how you can write a factorial in a while loop?

I can make it in an if / elif else statement:

```
num = ...
factorial = 1

if num < 0:
   print("must be positive")
elif num == 0:
   print("factorial = 1")
else:
   for i in range(1,num + 1):
       factorial = factorial*i
   print(num, factorial)
```

But I want to do this with a while loop (no function).

Comment: A `for` loop can be rewritten as a `while` loop. Set up your initial value for `i` before the loop; use the `while` condition to detect when `i` reaches its limit; increment `i` inside the loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
while num > 1:
    factorial = factorial * num
    num = num - 1
```

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to get a result: [math.factorial(x)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html)

While loop:

```
def factorial(n):
    num = 1
    while n >= 1:
        num = num * n
        n = n - 1
    return num
```